# ArcPy not executing CopyFeatures_management to write feature class to ArcSDE geodatabase

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, error-000210

I have some problems with my Python script. The script gets an JSON with different information about images. The information includes general information about images and also the gps position of them. Wih this information a featureclass should be generated that shows the location of the pictures as point geometry. The other information should be stored in the attribute table.

The script runs very well and is already deployed on ArcGIS Server 10.1. Now the problem is, that at the first start the featureclass has to be created. As the featureclass consists of about 92 attribute fields the process of creating the featureclass is done with the option "in memory" as this option guarentees a fast creation of the featureclass - it is at least faster then directly running `arcpy.addfield_management()` on a feature class that was created the other way.

The disadvantage is that I want to store the featureclass permanently in a ArcSDE geodatabase. For this I have to run one of the tools `arcpy.featureclasstofeatureclass_conversion` or `arcpy.copyfeatures_management`. If the script is trying to run on of these lines I get the error message 000210 that is telling me that the output cannot be generated.

The connection to the ArcSDE works fine, this cannot be the problem. I have full write and read access. Does anybody know what the error message is about and what could be one solution?

The script works fine if I am not using the "in memory" option for the feature class. So this error must have his origin in the "in memory" option. The log file of the Database gives only an general error message:

> Oracle : ORA-3137[3149]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why the in-memory workspace option isn't working for you, but there is probably a better way than what you are doing. Some ideas:

If the schema of each output feature class is going to be the same every time, you could simply copy an empty template feature class or use the [Import XML Workspace Document](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000014s000000) tool using a previously exported workspace document for your feature class schema.

[Create Feature Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002p000000) also gives you the option of using a template feature class or table for the field definitions.

Once you've done that you would load the data in using an [InsertCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w0000000t000000) or the [Append](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000050000000) tool.

If that's not specific enough, post your code, otherwise all you're going to get are general suggestions.